# iTerm always asks for user login before loading user's shell

Tags: terminal, login

I'm using macOS on Sonoma, and for as long as I remember, iTerm2 prompts me to log in with **user** *and* password each time before it loads the shell. This is quite tedious, and it always takes a few seconds to load my shell before I can start my session. On restart, it requires the user login again. The same does not happen with the native Terminal.

`.ssh`

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v173)
"   /Users/kamil/.ssh
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
known_hosts
```

What are some settings I might want to look at, and can this be related to the fact that iTerm is installed directly in root rather than the user `Applications` folder? In this case, would something other than re-install into `~/Applications` fix this behaviour?

`.zsh_sessions`

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v173)
"   /Users/kamil/.zsh_sessions
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
5D8E045B-C5F5-46A8-8033-0E877C823762.session
_expiration_check_timestamp
```

Comment: This is perfectly on topic here, but I think you are more likely to get an answer on our sister site, [apple.se], since this is bound to be some sort of macOS specific detail and the folks there will be more likely to know the answer. You might want to delete this and repost there instead.

Comment: Cross-posted (with adaption) to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468731/iterm-always-asks-for-user-login-before-loading-users-shell

Answer (score 0):

Either you have something in your .bash/zsh_profile (or .bash/zsh_login, or .profile) that is running a command that wants your password that the regular terminal is not asking for, or your terminal default session has been configured to ssh into another system (which could be localhost, aka yourself).

[source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2798097?answerId=13298756022&sortBy=best#13298756022)

Comment: I have gone through all files related to my shell and found two I was not able to understand. I have included their content in the post. May you see if one of your suggestions is on point or not? 

If it's not, I will ensure that no data will be lost if I re-install iTerm into `~/Applications` rather than having it in `/Applications` since that's probably it otherwise.